# What exactly is a dummy-it?

Tags: pronouns, dummy-pronouns

When someone, for example, reads a book or watches a movie, and they say:

> "It was a good movie"
> or
> "It was a good reading"

Are these kinds of sentences a dummy-it or just an "it" being used to refer to a noun, in these cases, the movie that was watched and the book read?

And by the way, I should always use a subject unless the subject is implied like in the imperative mood, right?

I just wanted to check this after reading this article of Thought.co, https://www.thoughtco.com/dummy-it-in-grammar-1690414

Comment: It seems like you haven't understood the article. "Dummy it refers to nothing at all; it simply serves a grammatical function. In other words, dummy it has a grammatical meaning but no lexical meaning." Here, there are clear meanings and referents: a movie and a reading. (Note, "a reading" usually means a passage that is read, like in a worship service or as a homework assignment. If we want to say that we enjoyed reading a book, the idiom is "It was a good read.")

Comment: Meanwhile, "And by the way, I should always use a subject unless the subject is implied like in the imperative mood, right?" —I don't quite understand this question, and it seems like a separate one; maybe open it separately.

Comment: Thanks for answering and the tip about a good read; the other question was just to confirm whether I could use sentences where "it" acts as subject without its presence or with its presence.

Answer (score 1):

When said in the context you describe, “It was a good movie” does not use a dummy *it*. The *it* has for antecedent the movie that has been watched and is being discussed.

An example of a sentence with a dummy *it* is ***It** was nearly midnight when the movie ended*.

Comment: In this case, *it* is being used as a dummy it to talk about weather, right

Comment: It’s talking about the time of day (or night). You can tell it’s a dummy because it would be nonsensical to ask in reply, “**What** was nearly midnight?”

Comment: Thanks, just, one more question, is it wrong to use sentences like that without the presence of it?

Comment: Sentences like what? \**Was nearly midnight* is not a valid English sentence. Nor, if you wish to know the hour, is it valid to ask, \*”What time is?” Nor indeed to enquire about the weather by asking, \*”Is raining?”

Comment: Yeah, I get what you mean. Thanks a lot, to be honest, I just saw this concept a while ago and since then my mind has been puzzled.