# What does “it” refer to in “it was too much to think of and sit still”

Tags: pronouns, parsing

The following quote is from Sister Carrie by Theodore Dreiser:

> He would plead until her anger would melt—until she would forgive him. Suddenly he thought: “Supposing she isn't out there—suppose she has gone. He was forced to take his feet. **It was too much to think of and sit still.** Nevertheless, his rousing availed him nothing.

What is the referent of the pronoun "it"?  Does "it" refer back to all the questions he turned over in his mind?   What is the object of the preposition "of" in "think of"?

Comment: **It** – the idea that she has gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.   I wonder if you can tell me the object of the phrasal verb "think of"?  I think the object of the preposition "of" is "it" referring to the fact that he was looking for her all the time."

Comment: The object is still **it**. You could rephrase as "It was too much to think of ***it*** and sit still" but then the first 'it' would refer to the situation.

Comment: Very much obliged to you for the quick response.  Would you please tell me the correct interpretation of "much" in this context?

Comment: "Much" parses as "too much". The sentence "It was too much to think of and sit still" means "It was impossible to sit still while thinking about the idea that she has gone."

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is a dummy-it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345290/what-exactly-is-a-dummy-it)

Answer (score 1):

I summarise what @Weather Vane commented.

> **It** was too much to think of and sit still.

The pronoun *it* refers to the thought that *she has gone*. The object of the preposition *of* in *think of* is *it*.

We can phrase the sentence as

> It was too much to think of *the scenario that she has gone* ...

We can also use *scenario* as shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!